# Not writing excessive amounts of code

Tags: php

So, I have this function that I am trying to run that looks like this:

```
function getValue($root, $i = null)
{
    if(isset($root[$i]['Hello'])
    {
        return $root[$i]['Hello'];
    }
    elseif(isset($root['Hello'])
    {
        return $root['Hello'];
    }
    else 
    {
        return '';
    }
}
```

I do not want `[$i]` to be there if it is null. How could I go about doing this without writing a lot of code that is basically repetitive?

Comment: What's repetitive? I'm not sure I understand what you want

Comment: `return (!empty($root[$i])) ? true : false;`

Comment: @Machavity I updated my question

Comment: This looks like you are trying to fix a symptom instead of the actual cause. Rarely a good idea.

Comment: @arkascha So, I have to write it out like this? Damn....

Comment: No, that is exactly _not_ what I suggest you do. I suggest you fix the cause, _not_ the symptom.

Comment: Its impossible to do this. I am dealing with the MWS API and they sometimes return some numeric stuff like in my example.

Comment: Added two variations.

Comment: Thanks. I will try and make this work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along the lines of

```
function getValue($root, $i = null)
{
    return $i ? isset($root[$i]) : isset($root);
}
```

if I understand what you're trying to achieve correctly.

With the question updated I think the shortest you can get away with is this:

```
function getValue($root, $i = null)
{
    $_t = isset($root[$i]) ? $root[$i] : $root;
    return isset($_t['Hello']) ? $_t['Hello'] : '';
}
```

https://3v4l.org/ZKtQi

Comment: I edited my question. I have to have it look something like that

Comment: Oh, that changes the game a bit... So you want to always query the `'Hello'` element no matter how deep in the array it is?

Comment: Yes. Most of the time it is in this kind of path `$root[$i]['Hello']` or `$root['Hello']`.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just check `$i` and use ternaries:

```
function getValue($root, $i = null)
{
    return (isset($i) && isset($root[$i]['Hello'])) ? $root[$i]['Hello'] : '';
    return (isset($root['Hello'])) ? $root['Hello'] : '';
}
```

You could probably nest the two ternaries above into one `return` but I would advise against it.

Along the lines of your current code:

```
function getValue($root, $i = null)
{
    if(isset($i) && isset($root[$i]['Hello']))
    {
        return $root[$i]['Hello'];
    }
    elseif(isset($root['Hello']))
    {
        return $root['Hello'];
    }
    else 
    {
        return '';
    }
}
```